# Python web scraping leaving gaps in MLB pull

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape MLB lineups from this link: https://www.baseballpress.com/lineups/2022-08-04 using Python. However, when I run the code below, it pulls the data into a dataframe, with the away teams in the "first_lineup" column and the home teams in the "second_lineup" column. The issue is that when it pulls the data into a the dataframe, it does not pull everyone.  Attached are screenshots of the data frame and of the website.  If anyone could help explain the issue, that would be great!  Thanks.

[image: Dataframe Code Output]

[image: Website example]

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.baseballpress.com/lineups/2022-08-04"

def get_names(item):
    try:
        player_name = item.get('data-razz').split("/")[-2].replace("+"," ")
    except IndexError: player_name = ""
    return player_name

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
first_lineup = [get_names(item) for item in soup.select(".col--min:nth-of-type(1) > a.player-link, [class$='col--min']:nth-of-type(1) .player > a.player-link")]
second_lineup = [get_names(item) for item in soup.select(".col--min:nth-of-type(2) > a.player-link, [class$='col--min']:nth-of-type(2) .player > a.player-link")]

df = pd.DataFrame({"first_lineup":first_lineup,"second_lineup":second_lineup})
df.to_csv("baseballpress.csv", encoding='utf-8', index=False)
print(df)
```

Comment: Please show your actual data frame as text and not a photo of your monitor.

Answer (score 0):

To get all players to a dataframe you can use next example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.baseballpress.com/lineups/2022-08-04"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")


def get_name(tag):
    if tag.select_one(".mobile-name"):
        tag.select_one(".mobile-name").extract()
    return tag


data = []
for card in soup.select(".lineup-card"):
    header = [
        c.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
        for c in card.select(".lineup-card-header .c")
    ]
    h_p1, h_p2 = [
        get_name(p).text for p in card.select(".lineup-card-header .player")
    ]
    data.append([*header, h_p1, h_p2])

    for p1, p2 in zip(
        card.select(".col--min:nth-of-type(1) .player"),
        card.select(".col--min:nth-of-type(2) .player"),
    ):
        p1 = get_name(p1).text.split(maxsplit=1)[-1]
        p2 = get_name(p2).text.split(maxsplit=1)[-1]

        data.append([*header, p1, p2])

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data, columns=["Team1", "Date", "Team2", "Player1", "Player2"]
)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
print(df.head(10).to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| Team1 | Date | Team2 | Player1 | Player2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Brewers | August, 4 12:35pm | Pirates | Brandon Woodruff (R) | Zach Thompson (R) |
| Brewers | August, 4 12:35pm | Pirates | Christian Yelich (L) DH | Tucupita Marcano (L) 2B |
| Brewers | August, 4 12:35pm | Pirates | Willy Adames (R) SS | Bryan Reynolds (S) DH |
| Brewers | August, 4 12:35pm | Pirates | Rowdy Tellez (L) 1B | Ben Gamel (L) LF |
| Brewers | August, 4 12:35pm | Pirates | Andrew McCutchen (R) LF | Ke'Bryan Hayes (R) 3B |
| Brewers | August, 4 12:35pm | Pirates | Kolten Wong (L) 2B | Oneil Cruz (L) SS |
| Brewers | August, 4 12:35pm | Pirates | Hunter Renfroe (R) RF | Bligh Madris (L) 1B |
| Brewers | August, 4 12:35pm | Pirates | Victor Caratini (S) C | Greg Allen (S) CF |
| Brewers | August, 4 12:35pm | Pirates | Mike Brosseau (R) 3B | Cal Mitchell (L) RF |
| Brewers | August, 4 12:35pm | Pirates | Jonathan Davis (R) CF | Jason Delay (R) C |

and saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help!  When I run this code, I receive the error "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)".  Do you know how to resolve this error?

Comment: @BenAhnen Do you run this code as is (because when I run the code it works)? Or do you change URL?

Comment: I copy and pasted your code exactly as you typed

Comment: @BenAhnen Then it must work. Make sure you haven't got captcha page, e.g. `print(soup)`

Comment: I'm sorry - I'm just learning Python. Should I be running print(soup) as a standalone function, or be adding it into the entire chunk?

Comment: @BenAhnen Right after `soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")`. Then make sure server hasn't sent captcha response and required tags are really there.

Comment: I added it in there and it is not indicating anything, however I am still receiving the same error.  It appears the error is occuring right after `h_p1, h_p2 = [`

Comment: @BenAhnen When I'm running the code on my computer, it works. You need to debug the code by yourself and find out where the error comes from.

Comment: Could this possibly be related to what I am running python out of?

Comment: could you explain why you use .mobile-name ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `data-razz` property for each player in your listing, but some of those are empty for some players like Seiya Suzuki, if you take a look at the HTML, you'll see his and Nico Hoerner's are missing this field.\

```
 <a class="player-link" data-bref="wisdopa01" data-mlb="621550" data-razz="https://razzball.com/player/13602/Patrick+Wisdom/" href="http://mlb.mlb.com/team/player.jsp?player_id=621550" target="_blank">Patrick Wisdom</a>
 <a class="player-link" data-bref="suzukse01" data-mlb="673548" data-razz="" href="http://mlb.mlb.com/team/player.jsp?player_id=673548" target="_blank">Seiya Suzuki</a>
 <a class="player-link" data-bref="hoernni01" data-mlb="663538" data-razz="" href="http://mlb.mlb.com/team/player.jsp?player_id=663538" target="_blank">Nico Hoerner</a>
```

Similarly, a number of players, probably due to name length, have additional selectors for `desktop-name` (which contains text for a full name, e.g. **Brandon Woodruff**) and `mobile-name` (containing a shortened name, e.g. **B. Woodruff**), like so:

```
<a class="player-link" data-bref="woodrbr01" data-mlb="605540" data-razz="https://razzball.com/player/605540/Brandon+Woodruff/" href="http://mlb.mlb.com/team/player.jsp?player_id=605540" target="_blank">
    <span class="desktop-name">Brandon Woodruff</span>
    <span class="mobile-name">B. Woodruff</span>
</a>
```

It doesn't look like your code as-is particularly cares about the actual razzball URL, so you could call `get_text()` on each field to get the player name as displayed via the `<p>` tags, with some additional checking to see if the player has a `desktop-name` field.

```
from bs4 import Tag

# ...stuff...
def get_player_name(t: Tag) -> str:
    if span := t.find("span", {"class": "desktop-name"}):
        return span.get_text()
    
    return t.get_text()
```

And then call it...

```
first_lineup = [get_player_name(t) for t in soup.select(".col--min:nth-of-type(1) > a.player-link, [class$='col--min']:nth-of-type(1) .player > a.player-link")]
second_lineup = [get_player_name(t) for t in soup.select(".col--min:nth-of-type(2) > a.player-link, [class$='col--min']:nth-of-type(2) .player > a.player-link")]
```

And now you should have the longer names for every player.

Comment: This worked for the most part, but when I run the code some of the names duplicate names, IE: Brandon woodruff shows up as "Brandon WoodruffB. Woodruff". Do you know why that would be?

Comment: @BenAhnen I updated my answer - some players had additional `span`s in their data that specified both `desktop-name` and `mobile-name`, so calling `get_text()` on them got both those names joined together. I changed `get_player_name` to check for the `desktop-name` (which is the full name of the player), otherwise just return `get_text` directly on the player link.

Comment: For the code starting bs4 import tag, is that in addition to everything else listed or what does it replace?  Thanks!

Comment: @BenAhnen just an additional import - I'm just using [type hinting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) to make it clearer what the function takes as input and what it returns. You can optionally remove it and change the method signature to not use types.